# How to parse result from Rust Actix awc::client to json and read json elements

Tags: json, rust, actix-web

I have request with awc::client, and has respond to Result - body.
How to read element from that result.

```rust
    let response = client.post("http://localhost:8002/trace_route")
        .send_json(&request)
        .await;

    let bodydata = response.unwrap().body().await;
    println!("Response: {:?}", bodydata);
```

return from that request is

```json
{
"matchings": [],
"tracepoints": []
}
```

How i get element tracepoint from that Result.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Use `response.unwrap().json()`

Comment: not work, error 
   |
72 |     let bodydata = response.unwrap().json();
   |         --------                     ^^^^ cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the associated function `json`

Comment: Idk why all the answers use `reqwest` despite this being an `awc` question. But I have provided an answer for `awc` 3.0.

Comment: Does anyone here know why it is so common for people to use unwrap like this rather than use a match on the result to avoid the panic (as I did in my answer to this question)?

Answer (score 1):

The response type provides a method `ClientResponse::json<T>` where `T` is the response type.

Given the struct `Trace` as:

```rs
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Trace {
   matchings: Vec<String>,
   tracepoints: Vec<String>,
}
```

You can get the response like this:

```rs
let mut response = client.get(uri).send().await.unwrap();
let response = response.json::<Trace>().await.unwrap();
```

Make sure, that the struct you want to deserialize into derives from `serde::Deserialize`.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, you need to use awc's `.json` [method](https://docs.rs/awc/latest/awc/struct.ClientResponse.html#method.json).
Let’s look at the method signature,

```
pub async fn json<T: DeserializeOwned>(self) -> Result<T>
```

There are two things to note here:

1. Rust is a typed language so the compiler needs to know the type `T` which specifically is part the return result.

If I were you I would do

```
struct Trace {
   matchings: Vec<String>,
   tracepoints: Vec<String>,
}
fn main() {

    let response = client.post("http://localhost:8002/trace_route")
        .send_json(&request)
        .await;

    let bodydata = response.unwrap().json::<Trace>().await;
    println!("Response: {:?}", bodydata);

}
```

You would think this would work but I hope you can guess what.

2. `T` must implement `serde::DeserializeOwned` which can easily be handled by a derive.

```
// This `derive` requires the `serde` dependency.
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Trace {
   matchings: Vec<String>,
   tracepoints: Vec<String>,
}
fn main() {

    let response = client.post("http://localhost:8002/trace_route")
        .send_json(&request)
        .await;

    let bodydata = response.unwrap().json::<Trace>().await;
    println!("Response: {:?}", bodydata);

}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused because this answer seems to reference `reqwest` but the question was about `awc`

Comment: Would you mind if I updated this answer to not use `.unwrap` and instead use a match arm on the `response` which is a `Result<SendRequestError,Clientresponse>`? See my answer below for example.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could find, there is still no real answer to this on StackOverflow. The accepted answer in this thread and the only other answer I found both use `reqwest`. I went ahead and read the `awc` docs, this goes for `awc = "3.0"`.

The `client.post().send_json().await.unwrap()` returns a [`ClientResponse`](https://docs.rs/awc/latest/awc/struct.ClientResponse.html#method.json), and panics if there are any client errors. Call `res.json().await` returns the `Future` trait impl of [`JsonBody`](https://docs.rs/awc/latest/awc/struct.JsonBody.html), which has its `Output` defined as `Result<T,JsonPayloadError>`.

There is also and alternative to using `client.post().send_json().await.unwrap()`, which is to just use `client.post().send_json().await`. Instead of working with a `ClientResponse`/panic, you have a  `Result<ClientResponse,SendRequestError>` to work with. The [`SendRequestError`](https://docs.rs/awc/latest/awc/error/enum.SendRequestError.html) can be handled with a `match` to catch client error events rather than panic:

```rs
use awc::{Client,error::JsonPayloadError};
use serde::{Deserialize};
use log::{error};

#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Trace {
   matchings: Vec<String>,
   tracepoints: Vec<String>,
}

async fn get_trace() -> Option<Trace> {
    let request_json = {"...you do you..."};
    // UPDATE 4/8/2023 replace unwrap with code that doesn't panic on request error
    let request_handle = client.post("http://localhost:8002/trace_route")
        .send_json(&request_json)
        .await;
    match request_handle {
        Ok(mut response_payload) => {
            let serde_result: Result<Trace,JsonPayloadError> = response.json().await;
            match serde_result {
                Ok(trace) => Some(trace),
                Err(json_err) => {
                    error!("Error parsing response:\n{:?}",json_err);
                    None
            }
        },
        // this seems safer than unwrap(), why am I the only one who did it?
        Err(send_request_error) => {
            error!("Error sending http request:\n{:?}",send_request_error);
            None
        }

    }
}

async fn async_main() {
    let client: Client = Client::default()
    json_result: Option<Trace> = get_trace().await;
    // trace will be a Trace instance below in the Some match arm
    match json_result {
        Some(trace) => println!("Success:\n{:?}",trace),
        None() => error!("See above")
    };
}

fn main() {
  block_on(async_main());
}
```